# Dockerfile TSC command is failing

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

Im kinda new to docker and Ive gone through a few iterations of this. just trying to get it running past the build step. My build:prod just runs "tsc". For some reason I'm getting the following error message:
[image]

Below is my current dockerfile. If there is anything yall could spot that would fix this issue, please let me know it would be greatly appreciated!

````
## DEPS ##
##########
FROM node:18-alpine AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat

WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package*.json pnpm-lock.yaml* ./

RUN yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i --prod


####################
## Native Binaries Deps ##
####################
FROM --platform=amd64 node:18-alpine AS binaries-deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat

WORKDIR /app

# Prisma client
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY prisma ./prisma
RUN npx prisma generate

#############
## BUILDER ##
#############
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=binaries-deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules

ENV NODE_ENV=production

COPY . .

RUN yarn add typescript

RUN yarn build:prod```
````

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `tsconfig.json` file in the project. In particular, set the [target field](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target) to `es2022` (as you are using node 18).

Comment: Ok I updated that and explicitly copied it into the dockerfile but still getting the same error message.